# Jquery AjaxError not triggered, can't handle 302 or other ajax response

Tags: jquery, status

//First sorry 4 my bad english

I have read a lot (lot lot !) of posts about this type of question here and all over the web but no one help me.

I use many jquery ajax request on my website, sometimes to get a JSON response, sometimes only to load php/html content inside the page.

I made a general function to send forms with jquery ajax method, all is working fine BUT now, I need to handle the 'status' of the XHR object because some ajax request need to be done by authenticated user, and I have to solve the problem of session timeout.

When session is timed out, XHR normally return 302 status, because on the ajax called page I do "header location xxx".

The probleme is "simple" : I don't succeed in handle 302 or like so status with jquery ajaxError

I would like to use jquery ajaxError function to handle all ajax request on my website.
Firebug show me 302 response AND location when I call a page with a header location, but jquery don't handle that... :(

Can you help me? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Update to jQuery 1.5. It allows to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {404: function() {
    alert('page not found');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot but... same result as jquery 1.4.2, 302 (followed by 200 because of php redirect ok) not handle :(

I work around with a little 'hack' :

```
$.ajaxSetup({complete: onRequestCompleted});
    function onRequestCompleted(xhr,textStatus) {
        if (xhr.status == 410) {
            window.location.href = xhr.getResponseHeader("Location");
        }
}
```

And on the ajax load page i put :

```
header("Location:".FILENAME_LOGIN_SESSION_TIMEOUT, true, 410);
```

It's working fine but... Is it a good practice?